# how to install volume pricing with spree 1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, installation, spree

I am working with rails 3.1.1 and Spree 1.0. Now I found a gem that really suits my requirements and that gem is spree volume pricing.

I read that the version of spree should be the same as this gem, so this gem only has the version 0.70 so I guess I have to install Spree 0.7 and now is when everything start crumble.

I would like to see a GemFile running "volume pricing" in order to see what do I have to install (and which versions). 
My idea is to install the latest versions, but of course that is not the simplest way. There are many combinations, and it is a pain when rails is not suitable for spree and spree is not suitable for volume pricing, and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stable version of Spree 1.0 was released on Feb 9. The latest `spree_volume_pricing` gem I could find was on `spree_edge` [here](https://github.com/paulsponagl/spree_volume_pricing/tree/spree_edge), it was updated last month. The Spree 0.7 was version was updated 3 months ago.

In this situation I would probably take a snapshot of my repo with git then experiment with installing the edge version of volume pricing, if it doesn't work then revert changes. This can be done with something like this in your gem file.

```
gem 'spree_volume_pricing', :git => "https://github.com/paulsponagl/spree_volume_pricing.git"
```

Spree does not list the volume pricing as a supported gem in 1.0, so this is just an idea if  you want to use Spree 1.0 instead of 0.7